# Rails encoding under Cygwin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eclipse, cygwin

I'm trying to develop a rails app under Cygwin and Eclipse. I use Ruby 1.9 and Rails 4.1.

I made sure, using `recode`, that all my files have the `Windows-1252` encoding and my Eclipse project uses the same. I've also tried to use `UTF8` in both places but this error keeps showing up:

```
incompatible encoding regexp match (Windows-1252 regexp with UTF-8 string)

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
# Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
# For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

Is this related to my Rails/Ruby (read, Rails source files being in the Windows encoding while my code is in UTF-8) setup under Cygwin?

[Rails Stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/YW2hDpCi)

Comment: there is nothing like "incompatible encoding regexp match (Windows-1252 regexp with UTF-8 string)" in the `stacktrace` posted

Comment: That's the thrown exception, the stactrace is the call that originates the exception.

Comment: @PedroMontotoGarcía are you still having an issue? If not, please choose an answer below, upvote helpful ones, or submit your own response with a detailed explanation.

Comment: I haven't solved it on Windows and I continued working on it on Linux with no issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add

`# encoding: utf-8`

to the top of every ruby source file

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I believe the problem comes from the Rails gem being in Windows-1252 and my code being in UTF-8.

I've updated the OP.

Comment: Depending on how @Pedro plans to run his programs, adding such a line will only be superfluous on Unix systems. It can also be a pain if there are many source files. In times like this, it is always best to adjust the user environment, and _not_ the programs.

Answer (score 0):

I found this link, which walks you through installing Rails via Cygwin on Windows. I know you already have it installed, but it includes making Cygwin recognize UTF-8 encoding.

http://collaborate.je/2014/08/setting-ruby-rails-windows-7-via-cygwin/

I do not know if you are using Windows at work or home. If the latter, you may want to spend a little time installing Ubuntu on VirtualBox. You would only need a few GB of space, with an entire Linux OS running as an app within Windows. This is ideal for Rails apps, as many tutorials recommend Unix, and even more companies use Unix to program and run servers.

(In case you don't know, Linux falls under the Unix category, which also includes Mac. Windows is difficult to work program in certain languages, because its kernel and directory structure are not designed the same as Unix. But, I am sure you know this. **:-)** )